# Java: applying 2 expressions to 1 scanner input

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to apply 2 conditions: read a character at a time and require alpha character input for the same scanner input:

Any suggestions on how to apply these conditions and continue checking each character user inputs?

```
Scanner lastname = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the first letter of last name:");
lastname.useDelimiter("(?<=.)");  
if (lastname.hasNext())  
    System.out.println("character: [" + lastname.next() + "]");
if (!lastname.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")); {
    System.out.println("You are not a robot so do not use numeric characters.");
  System.out.println("Please enter letter:");
    lastname.next();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the delimiter; change your logic.

Always just read one character, but test it using code like this:

```
String s = scanner.next();
if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)))
```

or using regex:

```
if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I added regex example.  Do you have any suggestions on how to allow multiple characters from input but display 1 at a time?  For example if user inputs R123o456b45  The output would display:

Comment: Don't set the delimiter. Just use `.hasNextLine()` and `.nextLine()` so the user has to press enter to give your program input, which is the usual way command line input works.